# Gradle: Execution failed for task ':linkMainExecutable'

Tags: c, gradle

I am trying to build a very simple and small C project from following link [building c executables](https://guides.gradle.org/building-c-executables/), but build failed with following error message:

```
Execution failed for task ':linkMainExecutable'.
> A build operation failed.
      Linker failed while linking main.exe.
  See the complete log at: file:///D:/xxxxx/build/tmp/linkMainExecutable/output.txt
```

If i look into `D:\xxxx\build\exe\main` directory, it seems it doesn't generates any main.exe file.

But GCC compiler seems working fine. I tried I tried  `gcc -o main main.c` command and that generates `main.exe` which outputs Hello, World.

Build environment looks ok, since it builds successfully when i run `gradle wrapper` or `gradlew` commands.

Below is the source code and you can also see the source code in above link.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "greeting.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf( "%s\n", GREETING_STRING);
    return 0;
}
```

**greeting.h**

```
#ifndef GRADLE_GUIDE_EXAMPLE_GREETING_H__
#define GRADLE_GUIDE_EXAMPLE_GREETING_H__

#define GREETING_STRING "Hello, World"

#endif
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin : 'c'

model {
    components {
        main(NativeExecutableSpec)
    }
}
```

**Java versions:**

- java version "1.8.0_141"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b15)
- Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)

Please see the complete log contents from output.txt which is generated by `gradlew -s mainExecutable`

```
See file:///D:/tutorials/c-executable/build/tmp/linkMainExecutable/output.txt for all output for linkMainExecutable.
linking main.exe failed.
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0\libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lstdc++
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmoldname
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwex
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.dll.a when searching for -lpthread
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.dll.a when searching for -lpthread
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ladvapi32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lshell32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -luser32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lkernel32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../..\libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -liconv
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmoldname
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwex
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Finished linkMainExecutable, see full log file:///D:/tutorials/c-executable/build/tmp/linkMainExecutable/output.txt.
```

Comment: Can you include the content of `output.txt` too?

Comment: contents of 'output.txt' are added in the post.

Comment: Just want to mention that if i look into `D:\xxxx\build\exe\main\` directory, there is no main.exe file which supposed to be generated while execution..

Comment: But GCC compiler seems working fine. I tried I tried "gcc -o main main.c" command and that generates "main.exe" which outputs Hellow, World.

Comment: You are building with a mingw in C:/Strawberry/c/bin. This is a `perl` installation of mingw. You need to install MinGW or Cygwin or most likely remove `c:/Strawberry/...` from the path

Comment: See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10-rc-2/userguide/native_software.html#native-binaries:tool-chain-support for required tool chain for gradle.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje, Thanks and your suggested solution worked! the problem was due to Strawberry Perl. But I needed the Strawberry Perl too. So, I put MinGW path before the Strawberry Perl's paths in Environment variable and now it looks OK :)

Answer (score 0):

`Mingw-w64` (as the log suggests) is not supported, not even by the latest Gradle `5.1.1`.

you can build with:

- GCC with Cygwin 32
- GCC with Cygwin 64 (not officially supported)
- GCC with MinGW
- Visual C++

Visual Studio appears to be the best option for building with Gradle, on a Windows system.

Comment: I was using Cygwin 64 and now I've installed Cygwin 32, in both cases I can see the same errors as above. I installed MinGW too, but seems it doesn't work with Gradle or at least I haven't seen an improvement.. However I haven't tried Visual Studio(yet)..